# Отладка в PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

Как посмотреть значения переменных находящихся в цикле, не в пошаговом режиме.
У меня приходят данные по COM портам, данные обрабатываются и сохраняются.
Необходимо видеть их в динамике. В программе создается форма (Tkinter) с выводом на нее графиков. У точек останова есть пункт suspend поясните как им пользоваться.